# Validation of custom Django fields

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-admin

There is a Django field type for storing values of `MyType`.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class MyTypeField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "text"

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            try:
                value = MyType.deserialize(value)
            except ParseError, e:
                raise ValidationError("Invalid format: "+str(e))
        assert isinstance(value, MyType)
        return value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, MyType):
            raise ValidationError("Not MyType")
        return value.serialize()
```

I am trying to use fields of this type on an admin page of a model. Everything works nice if a user enters a valid value in the field. But if the entered value is invalid, the `ValidationError` is not caught (you get error 500, or a stack trace if debug is enabled)

Instead I want to see the form with a message "Invalid format" near the field (just like if you enter an invalid date or number). How to modify the field class to get validation errors in a correct place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#modelforms-and-custom-fields

> If you use SubfieldBase, to_python()
>   will be called every time an instance
>   of the field is assigned a value. This
>   means that whenever a value may be
>   assigned to the field, **you need to
>   ensure that it will be of the correct
>   datatype, or that you handle any
>   exceptions.**

So a ValidationError will never be caught at this point. `to_python` is also called when populating a new instance of your model from the database, which is outside the form validation context.

> **Therefore, you must ensure that the
>   form field used to represent your
>   custom field performs whatever input
>   validation and data cleaning is
>   necessary to convert user-provided
>   form input into a
>   to_python()-compatible model field
>   value.** This may require writing a
>   custom form field, and/or implementing
>   the formfield() method on your field
>   to return a form field class whose
>   to_python() returns the correct
>   datatype.

So you have to move your validation into a formfield.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `clean(self, value, model_instance)` method in your field class and do the validation/raise the error there.

Comment: For `SubfieldBase` fields `clean` is not called. Probably I have to get rid of SubfieldBase (any examples?)